# NSDate from string is always nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I receive dates as `String` like this one:

> "2016-05-20T12:25:00.0"

I want to get its corresponding `NSDate` object, and I'm trying this way:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.s"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStr)
```

where `dateStr` is like the example I wrote first. I took the `dateFormat` string from [this page](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime), but I get a `nil` date, what is wrong there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: confirm that your dateStr format and your setter format is right or not

Comment: As documented in Apple's [Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html), NSDateFormatter uses the UTC date format patterns: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns . Your date format is just wrong.

Comment: you need set quotes for T, like "YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss.s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few problems with your date format. First `Y` is for weekOfYear, `D` is for day of year. `hh` is used for 12 hours format, decimal second you should use capital `S` and you need to escape the `'T'`

You should do as follow:

```
let dateString = "2016-05-20T12:25:00.0"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S"
if let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString) {
    print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date) )  // "2016-05-20T12:25:00.0\n"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S"
if let date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()) {
    print(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date) )  
}
```